# <Play!> Retrieving uniquely generated ID from <JPABase> in JPA

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-1.x

Folks,

I am using Play 1.2.5. The database is Oracle 10g and I am using an existing table for my application.

I am generating a unique key like this:

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
public int transactionId;
```

When I use the below code, the `transactionId` is generated and saved successfully ib the database:

```
transactionDetails.save();
```

But I am not able to get the uniquely generated `transactionId` once the save operation performs successfully. The save method returns a type `<JPABase>`. Then how can I retrieve the `transactionId` after a successful save operation from the `<JPABase>` ?

**Note:** I don't want to make another DB hit for fetching the `transactionId` because I believe that there might be some way to retrieve it for a successful save operation.

Please let me know about this.

Thanks,

Comment: Do you post your full code here?  `@GeneratedValue` cannot work alone, but must be used in conjunction with the `@SequenceGenerator` annotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to write

```
TransactionDetails savedDetails = transactionDetails.save();
```

save() method actually is not returning JPABase, it is declared as  so you will get the saved entity